# copy assignment operator= self-assignment check error

Tags: c++

If I have a class declared with

```
class Person
{
  public:
    Person(const int age);  // constructor
    Person(const Person & other);
    Person & operator=(const Person & other);  // copy assignment operator=
    ~Person();
};
```

and define self-assignment check like this

```
Person & Person::operator=(const Person & other)  // copy assign operator=
{
  if (*this != other)
  {... copy data ...}
  return *this;
}
```

then g++ issues an error:

> error: no match for `‘operator!=’` (operand types are `‘Person’` and `‘const Person`’)

But then if I change it to

```
Person & operator=(Person& other);
```

then g++ issues an error:

> error: no match for `‘operator!=’` (operand types are `‘Person’` and `‘Person’`)

Why, in the second case, no match if types are the same?

And a followup question:

Why only this check is considered valid ?

```
if (this != &other)
```

Comment: Please include your class definition. Have you overloaded your == or != operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter that the types are the same.  It matters whether or not the operator is not defined.  The compiler does not provide a default `operator!=` for you, and apparently you haven't defined it yourself.

In this case, however:

```
if (this != &other)
```

This is valid because it is a pointer comparison.  Pointer comparison is a built-in feature that is available to any pointer type.

Answer (score 4):

This check is incorrect: rather than checking the pointer, it checks the instance, calling the `operator !=(other)`.

You should change the line to

```
if (this != &other) {... copy data ...}
```

This way you would check the "identity" of your object, rather than checking the equality. Checking equality on pointers is very fast, but more importantly, that's the right thing to do. The whole point behind the check is to avoid destroying the content of your object in preparation to copying the data into it, only to find that you have just deleted your own data.

Comment: Not entirely true. `==` and `!=` are separate operators, and calling `!=` does not forward a call to `==`.

Comment: Do we agree that selfness test only make sense for classes that are holding a pointer and is useless if not ?